# Parallel Port Driver Install Fails (Debian)

Tags: linux, debian, driver

I have downloaded the drivers for a parallel card I bought (SD-PEX1005) and I am trying to install them now on my computer. The Readme says on versions of linux from 3.3.0 onward to use the folder /usr/src/linux-x.y.z/drivers/tty/serial/8250/ and change a file there called 8250_pci.c and then to re-compile the kernel. My problem is I don't have that folder.

Because I didn't have that folder I tried going about it the other way in the readme which was to go to the source folder and run 'make' but that fails every time.`https://pastebin .com/2v9WWA6q`

does anyone have any idea what I am missing either in my headers for the make command or for that file 8250_pci.c

for reference, I am on an installed version of linuxCNC. the results of 'uname -r' is 4.9.0-3-rt-amd64

here is the readme for the driver 
`https://pastebin .com/NYPLAA8g`

Comment: I do have a serial drivers folder but its at
/lib/modules/4.9.0-3-rt-amd64/kernel/drivers/tty/serial/8250/ and I don't have the .c file I need

Answer (score 0):

If you do not have the /usr/src/linux-x.y.z folder, you most likely do not the kernel source-code package installed.

Some Linux Distributions will install this by default. Others not.

The x.y.z would represent the Linux Kernel Version Number.

The Latest Kernel Source Code is available at kernel.org

For Debian Based Linux Distributions including Ubuntu, the "apt" command
is used to install software packages. The "apt" command has plenty of usage examples available from Ubuntu, and the Internet.

Try here to get the Kernel Source Code.

https://askubuntu.com/questions/159833/how-do-i-get-the-kernel-source-code

LinuxCNC may only work properly with specific kernels. Also, LinuxCNC requires the "Real Time" Kernel functions to be enabled.